# Not letting recipes break pages in the cuisine package

Tags: page-breaking

I just started using latex for my recipe book because using word was a mess. I found the cuisine package which is great, but i dont want my recipes to be split up into more than one page. So a recipe should be put into the next page if its too big for the current page.
I found this in in the package documentation:

> ifn@wpaging determines whether or not the next step will be on a new page.
> 14 \newif\ifn@wpaging

But frankly i dont know how to use this or if i interpret its meaning correctly.
Can someone tell me what i need to do in order to have only "full" recipes on a page?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[contents, nonumber]{cuisine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\RecipeWidths{1.3\textwidth}{3cm}{1cm}{3.5cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\renewcommand*{\recipestepnumberfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\recipetitlefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry} \begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\begin{recipe}{}{}{}
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please provide a small complete document illustrating your problem? In order to give advice we have to know your complete setup (in particular the preamble = packages + definitions), and usually we have to do a few experiments ourselves, for which we'd need a document to start from.

Comment: Thank you!
<\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[contents, nonumber]{cuisine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\RecipeWidths{1.3\textwidth}{3cm}{1cm}{3.5cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\renewcommand*{\recipestepnumberfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\recipetitlefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\begin{recipe}{}{}{}
\end{recipe}

This is the structure.